# Testing devise custom session controller with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I'm having custom controller

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    binding.pry
    super
  end
end
```

routes added

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }
```

and it works during signin using browser. But inside controller test breakpoint inside create is not being hit:

```
RSpec.describe Users::SessionsController, type: :controller do

  describe 'POST #create' do

    context 'pending activation user with expired password' do
      it 'could not login' do
        user = create :operator_user, status: User.statuses[:activation_pending], password_changed_at: (1.day + 1.second).ago
        @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
        sign_in user

        user.reload
        expect(user).to be_locked
      end
    end
  end

end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  #...
  # Devise methods
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  # ...
end
```

I expect expression
sign_in user
to fall into create method that I've overrided. What am I doing wrong?

ps: it even falls into standard devise [SessionsController#create](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to send request to controller by using `post :create, params: {...}` inside your example instead of `sign_in user`